# System.IndexOutOfRangeException at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteValueDictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

We have a .NET Core 2.1 application in production on Azure. It has been, infrequently, coming down with an unrecoverable 500 error which necessitates a site restart. We have noticed the following exception/stack trace appearing in our Azure application insights log hundreds of times at these times:

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteValueDictionary.ListStorage.Clear()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteValueDictionary.Clear()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteData.RouteDataSnapshot.Restore()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteCollection.<RouteAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestLocalizationMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Extensions.MapMiddleware.<Invoke>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.IISMiddleware.<Invoke>d__11.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.RequestServicesContainerMiddleware.<Invoke>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Frame`1.<ProcessRequestsAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
```

Its confusing and frustrating, as at first glance none of the involved code seems to be ours, but perhaps its due to some sort of misconfiguration in our routing?

For reference our UseMvc call:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    var section = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:HostNames");
    var hostnames = section.Get<string[]>();

    // Prepare special routes
    routes.MapRoute("takeSurveyApi", "TakeSurvey/{action}/{id?}", new { controller = "TakeSurvey", action = "Index" });
    routes.MapRoute("takeSurvey", "TakeSurvey/{id?}", new { controller = "TakeSurvey", action = "Index" });
    routes.MapRoute("stripeWebhook", "Billing/WebHook", new { controller = "Billing", action = "WebHook" });

    routes.MapSubdomainRoute(
        hostnames,
        "MHP",
        "{tenant}",
        "MHP/{action}",
        new { controller = "MHP", action = "GetTenantDetails" });

    routes.MapSubdomainRoute(
        hostnames,
        "Localisation",
        "{tenant}",
        "Localisation/{action}",
        new { controller = "Localisation", action = "Get" });

    routes.MapSubdomainRoute(
        hostnames,
        "TenantInSubdomain",
        "{tenant}",
        "{*url}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });

    routes.MapRoute(
        hostnames,
        "DefaultRoute",
        "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });               

    routes.MapRoute(
        hostnames, "reactRouter", "{*url}", new {controller = "Home", action = "Index"});
});
```

Has anyone encountered a similar set of circumstances before?

Comment: Agreed that this seems to be internal to ASP.NET Core, as such I'd suggest filing an issue [in the GitHub repo](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues) - they would most likely be best equipped to inform you if you're doing something wrong, or have encountered a bug.

Comment: I've raised a ticket over there, if theres a relevant outcome from it I'll cross-post https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/8499